# Video lecture available for Java programming

Tags: java, video

Is there any nice video lecture available for Java programming ?

Where I can learn the basics very nicely like CS61B lectures Java and its implementations on data structure...

Comment: Yes, there are. Is there anything more to your question?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Intro vs. Advanced? GUI programming? Web app programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Search](http://www.google.co.za/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=video+tutorial+on+java) brings the result. The results (from Google):

- [Java Video Tutorials](http://www.javavideotutes.com/)
- [IntelligentEdu](http://www.intelligentedu.com/blogs/post/best_new_training_sites/3707/top-40-java-video-tutorials-on-youtube)

Answer (score 0):

There are Code Casts aimed at Java beginners using the Eclipse IDE here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsetutorial/files/1.%20Total%20Beginners/